# Monthly data with seasonality: is linear regression appropriate?

Tags: regression, time-series, seasonality, aggregation

I have the following situation: there is data for six years, per month. In a year you can see variation per month, since the data is influenced by the seasons. Also, there is an upward trend over the years.
Would it be appropriate to aggregate data to years, and perform linear regression? My concern is that the $n$ would be incorrect, since I would end up with $n = 6$. Additionally, the seasonality would not be taken into account, but I am not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. What is your data? What model do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess about the main basis of your question is the concern around whether or not you should aggregate your time-based data, so my discussion here revolves around that in particular.

To summarize, I would say it depends on your data and what you want to do. Generally speaking, condensing a list of values into a sum or mean can potentially normalize and simplify your data structure, but it also comes at a potential loss of information (for instance you cannot calculate any variance/fluctuation in these months now that you only have a single measure per month). Because you specifically mention time-based influences on your data, I use an example based around that.

Here I have plotted some of my own productivity habits over the past couple years, one that charts daily minutes of work, the other monthly mean minutes of work. You can see that the left plot has the following pros:

- Just heuristically, there is a rich amount of information here in general.
- The fluctuation with each day provides a *lot* of variance that can better inform a statistical model.
- There is no guesswork here...the data is completely known.

whereas it has the following cons:

- There are several zero-values, which make it problematic for a vanilla linear regression.
- It is quite erratic, which makes modeling it more complex.
- Because of the density of information, it is difficult to meaningfully summarize effects.

[image]

Because of these points, you have to weigh which relationship better suits your needs. To add to that, time data is also more often *non-linear* rather than *linear*, though this isn't necessarily a law. Transformations such as these may help address this issue sometimes, particularly if you have a small number of *aggregated* time points that do not fluctuate too much. However, fitting a linear regression with "non-negotiable" nonlinearity is in itself a problem, as it is one of the assumptions that come with fitting a linear model. From what you mentioned, you say there is an "upward trend", but its not entirely clear if that means it is universally upward (aka linear) or "mostly" upward (aka nonlinear).

If the latter is true, one thing you could consider is something like a generalized additive model (GAM), which relaxes this assumption if you have enough data to construct the splines necessary. Here I fit both a linear regression and a GAM to the daily data (the monthly data simply doesn't have enough data points to construct a meaningful GAM), and here you can see the time fluctuations in productivity are better modeled by the splines from the GAM.

[image]

If my math is correct, you have about $n=72$ time points before aggregation ($\text{12 months} \times \text{6 years} = 72$). I think this wouldn't inherently be a problem for fitting a GAM contingent on how much flexibility you want (I've seen some fit with fairly small samples in the past), but I would like to stress that GAMs also potentially estimate a lot more coefficients than a typical linear regression, so this may affect the statistical power of your results contingent upon how your data behaves.